# Python urllib2 error

Tags: python, urllib2

I am trying to open a page using `urllib2` but i keep getting connection timed out errors.

```
url = "http://" + "100.12.13.11/api.php"
f = urllib2.urlopen(url)
```

I have two static IPs: `100.12.13.12`, LAN IP - `10.10.209.2`, domain - `test.com`; and `100.12.13.11` , LAN IP - `10.10.209.1`, domain - `test2.com`.

When I access

```
http://100.12.13.11/api.php
```

from the server at `100.12.13.12` using `urllib2`, it says connection timeout error.

Also if I use the domain, for example

```
http://test.com/api.php
```

the same thing happens but it works whenever I use the LAN IP

```
http://10.10.209.1/api.php
```

(both of the static IPs are in the same network)

The problem doesn't occur whenever I access from outside the network. But, in PHP, it works for domain name, static IP and LAN IP.

Does anyone know why this strange thing is happening?

Comment: Could you please better describe your problem? I do not understand how you tested that the "server" accept connections from your "client" before pointing to a python issue. Also, you example cannot be functional, it misses quotes and the (presumably) "http://" prefix so urllib2 knows which port and protocol to use.

Comment: i already uses http:// but it does not respond but i access same url with different programming language for example php it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually LAN's disallow local access to global IP's or domains hosted locally.Solution is to map the global hostname to the local IP in your local DNS.